# R: weighted summary

Tags: r, summary, weighted

I have survey, where people sort animals by their popularity.
for example:

```
"first","second","third"
"dog","cat","rabbit"
"cat","rabbit","dog"
"dog","cat","rabbit"
"dog","cat","rabbit"
```

I want graph, which shows order.
So animals in first column get weight 3, in second weight 2 and in third weight 1.

When i do:

```
data<-read.csv("animals.csv", header=T)

f = summary(data$first)
s = summary(data$second)
t = summary(data$third)
```

In **f** is array with:

```
dog      cat 
  3        1
```

In **s** is array with:

```
cat      rabbit
  3           1
```

In **t** is array with:

```
dog      rabbit
  1           3
```

And i obviously cannot do:

```
graph = 3*f + 2*s + t
```

Because they dont have the same column.
Exist some function how to do it. How to make weighted combination of these three columns?

In the end i need:

```
dog      cat     rabbit
 10        9          5
```

I am a begginer in R, so thank for help.

Comment: Please show the weighted combination you expect as output from your example.

Comment: do you mean you want 10 dogs, 9 cats and 5 rabbits at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the weighted numbers, you can do:

```
table(c(rep(data$first, 3), rep(data$second, 2), data$third))

#   cat    dog rabbit 
#    9     10      5
```

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(first = c("dog", "cat", "dog", "dog"), second = c("cat", 
"rabbit", "cat", "cat"), third = c("rabbit", "dog", "rabbit", 
"rabbit")), .Names = c("first", "second", "third"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

***NB:*** if the data are imported with characters as factors, you can do:

```
table(c(rep(as.character(data$first), 3), rep(as.character(data$second), 2), as.character(data$third)))
```

Comment: @user295691, maybe but they can be imported as characters or just wrap in `as.character` if not

Comment: Correct result has different order of "as.character" and "rep": 
table(c(as.character(rep(data$first), 3), as.character(rep(data$second), 2), as.character(data$third)))

Comment: @Zerig, I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment, do you want the results to be ordered ?

Comment: When i use rep(as.character... i get: cat 3, dog 3, rabbit 3. But when i use as.character(rep.... i get: cat 9, dog 10, rabbit 5
Thats all